# Loop through array in array with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Working on a TODO-app to learn Angular. I have this hardcoded array as a "database" and i want to display the tasks in the view.

```
var taskLists = [

    {name: 'Todays todo', id: '1', tasks:['Make coffe', 'another task']},
    {name: 'Tomorrow i will do this', id: '2', tasks:['Code well', 'go to bed']}

];
```

So how do i iterate through an array inside an array in an angular-view?
I tried to have two ng-repeats but cant get it to work right. I want to display the tasks one by one as `<td>`, not just the whole tasks array as one `<td>` as it does right now ['Make coffe', 'another task']

This is what the view looks like.

```
<h2 ng-repeat="object in list">{{object.name}}</h2>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>Tasks</tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="task in list">{{task.tasks}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you second `ng-repeat` shouldn't be `ng-repeat="task in object.task"` ?

Comment: You were right, it should be `task in object.tasks`. Plus the HTML from the answer below did the trick.

Comment: Oh yes, sure, the first repeat was only on the `<h2>` tag, i did not notice that :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem in your logic.

Fist your HTML tag from child must be inside the parent.

```
<div class="parent" ng-repeat="object in list">
    <h2>{{object.name}}</h2>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>Tasks</tr>
        </thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="task in object.tasks">
            <td>{{item}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Try this and check if it works.

Comment: To have the second ng-repeat inside parent did the trick. Thank you!